# Java Hosting Package can't be installed

Tags: iis, hosting, war, heliconzoo

I'm trying to install the Java Hosting Package distributed by Helicon Zoo in order to host a java project (.war file) on IIS. The problem I'm having is that I can't install the package because Jetty 8 can't be installed.

At first it complained about Jetty 7 aswell but after I downloaded it, that was removed. This didn't however work for Jetty 8.

Error message on web platform installer (Screenshot):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUeAW.jpg

Has anyone seen this before and possibly fixed it?

Comment: It looks like the installer tries to download something during install. Does your server have a working internet connection (that does not need a proxy / proxy authentication)  ?

Comment: Hmm, It seems as if the url that the package is trying to fetch Jetty from: http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-hightide-8.1.7/jetty-hightide-8.1.7.v20120910.zip has been shut down. I removed Jetty8 (which I manually installed to try to fix the issue, and downloaded it again from http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/. This seems to have fixed the issue. Don't know what the issue was with the first download but maybe it was corrupt.

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the inconvenience. For past two years we have been working on a new stand-alone version of Zoo - a complete, cross-platform (in future) web application and environment installation-packaging-deployment-execution suite. And we are doing it on a very limited resources. Plus we have to support old commercial products - our only source of funds in this development. So I decided to completely freeze current WebPI-based version of Zoo, there will be little common between these versions. Please allow us some more time to finalize this new version. Application migration will be easy.

Comment: Thank you @Yaroslav for the feedback. I managed to solve the problem by manually download Jetty 8. Thank you for the continued work on this product!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, It seems as if the url that the package is trying to fetch Jetty from: dist.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-hightide-8.1.7/… has been shut down. I removed Jetty8 (which I manually installed to try to fix the issue, and downloaded it again from download.eclipse.org/jetty. This seems to have fixed the issue. Don't know what the issue was with the first download but maybe it was corrupt.